# Compiler limits on number of overloads?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I am writing code to serialize objects of a number of different classes. To do this, I am planning to write an overload of a `serialize` function for each class that needs to be written. This means about 200 overloads or even more.

Do C++ compilers impose any limits to the number of overloads a function can have? What about overloads of member functions and constructors? Where would such limits (if any) be documented?

Comment: You would have to ask your compiler vendor to get an accurate answer.  A common answer would be "as memory permits", symbol table implementations in compilers are normally quite flexible.  Don't expect it to compile very fast, a compiler considers all overloads to pick the best one.  If the first pass through the candidates cannot immediately dismiss an overload then something might well go bang!

Comment: ^ Go bang meaning a compiler error?

Answer (score 2):

Internally, for every implementation I know, overloaded functions work the same as separate functions. The internal name for a function is just a "mangled" version of the function name that also encodes the argument types. So you are really asking, "How many functions can my program have?" I do not know what the spec says, but the practical answer on any modern system is certainly millions and probably billions.